# Using an Angular library from another repo without deploying it

Tags: angular, angular-library

Is it possible to have an Angular application reference the dist folder from another repo in the compilerOptions/paths entry in tsconfig.json?

I have the two repos checked out at the same level in the folder structure.

~/Developer/git/lib-project

~/Developer/git/app-project

I have tried adding the dist for the library into the apps tsconfig.json but can't seem to get it to work.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "lib": ["~/Developer/git/lib-project/dist/lib"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried absolute paths and many depths of ../

../lib-project/dist/lib

../../lib-project/dist/lib

../../../lib-project/dist/lib

../../../../lib-project/dist/lib

../../../../../lib-project/dist/lib

../../../../../../lib-project/dist/lib

But I cannot seem to get it to work. Is there a way to get the Angular app to use the lib without having to deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with a symlink. I created a symlink called dist in the app project that points to the dist folder in the lib project. Then an entry in compilerOptions/paths

```
"lib": ["dist/lib"]
```

works.